# How to protect routes in express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

For example, in Meteor, there's something like

```
Router.plugin('ensureSignedIn');
Router.plugin('ensureSignedIn', {
  except: ['home', 'atSignIn', 'atSignUp', 'atForgotPassword']
});
```

So unsigned user cannot access other routes except above four.

How to do this in express.js? I'm using passport.js also.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Meteor, but you can do something like the following, assuming you want to make pages available to only authenticated users (passport).

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();
  else
    // Return error content: res.jsonp(...) or redirect: res.redirect('/login')
}

app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  // Do something with user via req.user
});
```

The `ensureAuthenticated` function is just an example, you can define your own function. Calling `next()` continues the request chain.

Comment: Is there any npm libs ? By using above function, I have to add this function in every `app.get`

Comment: No idea, if you want to protect a set path you can use middleware e.g `app.use('/user/*', ensureAuthenticated)` will protect any matching routes.

Comment: How do you write unit tests for this route since it's protected and you cannot pass next...

Answer (score 0):

I should use middleware for protect my routes, even to protect certain verbs in the same route:

for example: in `my endpoint/route.js`

```
 // the require sentences are omitted 

const express = require('express');
const { /*controllerFunctions*/ } = require('./controller');
const {routeGuard} = require('/*must create a route guard*/');
const router = express.Router();


router.route('')
  .get(getAllResources) 
;

 router.route('/:id') // 
     .get(validateParam,getOneResource);


 router.use(routeGuard);

 router.route('/:id')
    .post(validateParam,validateBody,postResource)
    .patch(validateParam,validateBody,patchProblemById) 
    .delete(validateParam,deleteResource)    
    ;

 module.exports = router;
```

and my `routeGuard` file should be like this:

```
 const { promisify } = require('util');
 const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
 const AppError = require('./appError');
 const {User} = require('./../endpoints/users/model');
 const wrapper = require('./try-wrapper');//try catch wrapper

 module.exports.routeGuard = wrapper(async function (req, res, next){
    // the err message is the same on purpose
    const notAllowed = new AppError('Unauthorized: Invalid or Nonexistent credentials',401);

    let token = null;
    if (req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.startsWith('Bearer')){
        token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
    }
    if (!token) return next(notAllowed );

    const payload = await promisify(jwt.verify)(token,process.env.KEY);
    const user = await User.findById(payload.id);

    if (!user) return next( notAllowed);
    if ( ! user.hasSamePasswordSince(payload.iat) )return next( notAllowed ); 
    req.user = user; // further use...
    next(); 
});
```